# Create block variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray, objective-c-blocks

I have function, where I add block variable **blockIfLoadingImageFromServer** to array:

```
- (UIImage *)getImageWithblockIfLoadingImageFromServer:(void (^)(UIImage *imageCompleted))blockIfLoadingImageFromServer
{
      [array addObject:blockIfLoadingImageFromServer];
}
```

Then I want to get this variable, but I don't know how. I tried:

```
(void (^)(UIImage *imageCompleted))blockIfLoadingImageFromServer = [array objectAtIndex:0];
void (^)(UIImage *imageCompleted) *blockIfLoadingImageFromServer = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

But that gives an error (bad syntax). How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually `typedef` to make my life easier:

```
typedef void (^ImageBlock)(UIImage*);
```

And then:

```
- (void) doSomethingWithBlock: (ImageBlock) block
{
    [array addObject:[block copy]];
}

- (void) doSomethingElse
{
    ImageBlock block = [array lastObject];
    …
}
```

Comment: also [array addObject:[blockIfLoadingImageFromServer copy]];